# Shopify Tags total items

Tags: php, shopify

In Shopify, how do I show a list of tags followed by the number of products with that tag?

Example: Black(12), Blue(10).

Currently the code looks like this, but it doesn't work.

```
<ul>
    {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
        <li>
            <a href="https://mystore.myshopify.com/collections/all/{{ tag }}">
                {{ tag }}
            </a>
            ({{ tag.products_count }})
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in that code snippet?

Comment: ({{ tag.products_count }}) Counter is not working'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`products_count` is an attribute of [`collection`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-variables/collection), not `tag`.

I believe you would need to manually loop through the products and count the number with the specified tag.

For example:

```
{% assign collection = collections.all %}

<ul>
    {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}

        {% assign products_count = 0 %}
        {% for product in collection.products %}
            {% if product.tags contains tag %}
                {% assign products_count = products_count | plus: 1 %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        <li>
            <a href="https://mystore.myshopify.com/collections/all/{{ tag }}">
                {{ tag }}
            </a>
            ({{ products_count }})
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

See these similar discussions on the Shopify forums:

- [Show item count associated with a tag](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/show-item-count-associated-with-a-tag-55175)
- [Collection Tag Product Count (non-current view)](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/collection-tag-product-count-non-current-view-46272)
- [Getting Products By Tags When in a Collection](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/getting-products-by-tags-when-in-a-collection-111353#comment-111518)

Comment: Steph has the workaround above. However, this feature just got requested on the shopify/liquid project, hopefully it gets accepted: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/367

Comment: @BjornForsberg that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Solution by Steph is working. But, if i have enabled grouped tags and want to show product count. Kindly let me know solution to append product count in following code:

```
'{%comment%} code for color, designer, material sidebar filter {%endcomment%}

          {%- for tag in collection.all_tags -%}
            
            {%- assign tag_parts = tag | split: '_' -%}

            {%- if tag_parts.size != 2 -%}
              {%- continue -%}
            {%- endif -%}

            {%- assign groups = groups | append: tag_parts.first | append: ',' -%} 
          {% endfor %}


    {%comment%} End of  code for color, designer, material sidebar filter {%endcomment%}'
```