# Shopify counts per tags

Tags: shopify

I am new to shopfiy.I have addded tags like Black, Blue, Green etc.
Now i want to show count  like

> Black(12)
>
> Blue(1)
>
> Green(4)

Does anybody help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

My answer to a similar question might help you with this: [Shopify Tags total items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031787/shopify-tags-total-items/24035539#24035539)

To get a count of all the products with a given tag you need to loop over the products and manually count them.

For example:

```
{% assign collection = collections.all %}

{% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
    {% assign products_count = 0 %}
    {% for product in collection.products %}
        {% if product.tags contains tag %}
            {% assign products_count = products_count | plus: 1 %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    <p>{{ tag }} ({{ products_count }})</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Steph has the workaround above. However, this feature just got requested on the shopify/liquid project, hopefully it gets accepted: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/367

Comment: @Steph Sharp, Can you help me out in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768814/tag-count-automatically-changing-while-clicking-on-the-product-tag?noredirect=1#comment86558013_49768814